# Animate spinning image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview

I have a image that I would like to keep spinning if a button is pressed, until I call an action to stop the spinning. I tried these websites: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/15/rotate-animation-in-swift/ I had to made chances to the delegation, it crashes when I try to changed it
and https://bencoding.com/2015/07/27/spinning-uiimageview-using-swift/ just does not spin when I call the action. Thank you. Code is here below:

Andrewcbancroft.com:

```
    extension UIView {
    func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0)
        rotateAnimation.duration = duration

        if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
            rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate //<- error "Cannot assign value of type 'AnyObject' to type 'CAAnimationDelegate?'"
        }
        self.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

Trying to cast delegate as! CAAnimationDelegate will crash the application with error code Could not cast value of type 'test.ViewController' (0x1074a0a60) to 'CAAnimationDelegate' (0x10cede480) when trying to rotate the image.

Bending.com:

```
extension UIView {
    func startRotating(duration: Double = 1) {
        let kAnimationKey = "rotation"

        if self.layer.animation(forKey: kAnimationKey) == nil {
            let animate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
            animate.duration = duration
            animate.repeatCount = Float.infinity
            animate.fromValue = 0.0
            animate.toValue = Float(M_PI * 2.0)
            self.layer.add(animate, forKey: kAnimationKey)
        }
    }
    func stopRotating() {
        let kAnimationKey = "rotation"

        if self.layer.animation(forKey: kAnimationKey) != nil {
            self.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: kAnimationKey)
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to call my image view to start rotating in my viewDidLoad method, nothing happens.

Comment: No one is going to read the code on those sites and write code for you.  Post the code you've tried and error messages.

Comment: Ok I updated it

Answer (score 0):

Errors explained:

You're passing the delegate in as `AnyObject`

```
func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil)
```

`AnyObject` doesn't conform to `CAAnimationDelegate`, so you can't use it as the delegate.

If you're certain you're passing in a controller that can be a proper delegate, then cast it to the right kind of delegate:

```
if let delegate = completionDelegate as? CAAnimationDelegate {
    rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate
}
```

If you're doing this and it's crashing:

```
rotateAnimation.delegate = completionDelegate as! CAAnimationDelegate
```

Then you're not passing in a controller that conforms to `CAAnimationDelegate`

It might be simpler to not pass the delegate in at all and assign it outside of the extension.